# Find The distance covered by the Falling Circle.

Tags: geometry

### Find The distance covered by the Falling Circle.

lower point of the 1st circle is A. the first circle touch the point B on the line. the falling circle stop at point C.
the red circle falling to the line straight  as soon as it touch the line it start rotate to the lower side of the line (to the circle 3. ).   x1,y1,r1 is the coordinate of center and radius  of the 1st circle  ,     x2,y2,r2, for 2nd circle and x3,y3,r3 for 3rd circle.find the distance AB+BC.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Find a common tangent to circles 2 & 3 such as the one shown in figure. Find a point B on the tangent having x-coordinate = x1. Let the circle 3 touch the tangent at point P(can be easily computed). Calculate BP(using the coordinates) and CP(knowing the radii of the circles and the fact that they touch each other). Then BC = BP - CP. AB can also be calculated using coordinates.

Comment: but how to find a common tangent ? I don't know the formula. please explaine

Comment: and also don't know how to calculate CP.